# Is there an equivalent API of chrome.debugger in android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

[chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API can be used to communicate between chrome dev tools and chrome debug target. I wonder if there is a equivalent for android app of chrome.debugger, If there is, then I can use it to debug android webviews without physically connect my android device with my development machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ADB over WiFi?
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: chrome dev tools can debug android webviews. I assume that happens over adb. adb works over the network.

Comment: @MorrisonChang 
I know of ADB over Wifi, but it only works in LAN, and it's not suitable to be set up programmatically, if I want to debug a user's webview in production, it is not capable.

Comment: I'll also assume you are familiar with weinre  http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html You may want to list out your requirements beyond the 'not physically connected' and your definition of 'production' as debug is a elevated permission state (with the usual headaches about programmatic setup on non-rooted devices).